# Should a foreign key violation be a client error, and if so, how should it be handled?

Tags: go

I'm trying to wrap my head around a pragmatic way to handle database errors related to client input in my web application. For example, if I catch foreign key violations, I don't believe that should be a 500 since the user provided improper data. I also want to return which field in the client's request caused the foreign key violation (another case could be a unique constraint). All the solutions I've come up with so far result in my db package depending on the `net/http` package or my own http handler packages.

Here's a watered down example of my code:

```
// this implements an interface that's omitted for brevity
type ClientError struct {
    Code       int
    LogMessage string
    LogRequest *http.Request
    Body       interface{}
}

// this implements an interface that's omitted for brevity
type ServerError struct {
    LogType    string
    LogMessage string
    LogRequest *http.Request
}

// in my http handler package
func (h *ApiHandler) PostSomething(c *gin.Context) {
    // request parsing omitted for brevity

    // insert the review media metadata into the database. the location owns the media
    err := h.db.InsertRecord(parsedRequest)
    if err != nil {
        // if we didn't account for the error, it's an internal error
        if errors.Is(err, cerrors.ErrUnknown) {
            c.Error(ServerError{"db", err.Error(), c.Request})
            return
        }
        // otherwise, this function catches invalid data from the client
        c.Error(ClientError{
            Code:       http.StatusBadRequest, // what if I wanted to return other 4xx based on my db logic?
            LogMessage: "failed insert",
            LogRequest: c.Request,
            Body:       someObject,
        }).SetType(gin.ErrorTypePublic)
        return
    }

    c.Status(http.StatusCreated)
}

// in my db package
func (db *DB) InsertRecord() error {
    // some insert statement, and scan the result
    var result someVariable
    if err := row.Scan(&result); err != nil {
        if pqErr, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
            // foreign key violations
            c := pqErr.Constraint
            if c == "unq_violation" { 
                return ErrUnqViolation // ex: handled as a 409
            } else if c == "fk_some_fk" {
                return ErrFkSomething // ex: handled as a 400
            } else {
                return ErrUnknown
            } 
            // etc. for example, what if I wanted to return various 4xx 
            // or is this a bad idea in general

        }
    }
}

// note: using the gin framework, I also have some middleware that does some logging
// based on ClientError vs. ServerError
```

Note: I took inspiration for the error handling [here](https://medium.com/@ozdemir.zynl/rest-api-error-handling-in-go-behavioral-type-assertion-509d93636afd)

How can I cleanly return http based errors, such as the 400 or 409, from my db handlers without depending on the http package, and without having an if statement for every db error type in my http handler (i.e. grouping all 4xx errors into one category)? Should I just move my `ClientError` and `ServerError` to another package (to avoid a circular dependency) and return `Client/ServerError` directly from my db package, or is that bad coupling?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @TsujiDaishiro made an edit where I tried to summarize what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: If you want to change the http status code based on the error contained in the db package, you can use your http handler package that handles errors, you can use the db package. It seems natural to use errors to branch.

If you don't want the http handler package to depend directly on the db package, you can use between the http handler package and the db package layer, e.g., app. package, the app package contains the errors of the db package, and the app package contains its own errors to the http handler package.

Answer (score 5):

If that violation originates from a client request (*e.g.* issuing a `POST` to a REST endpoint), then it should be a client error. Server errors should be reserved to errors such as erroneous code or faulty infrastructure.

There is no strict rule to determine the appropriate HTTP response status code. `HTTP 409 - CONFLICT` is usually reserved to indicate a kind duplication (*e.g.* posting data that would violate a `UNIQUE` constraint), that may or may not apply here, depending on what you mean by “foreign key violation”. If you meant a violation as “foreign key value does not correspond to any entity `id`”, the status code `HTTP 422 - UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY` feels more appropriate to me.

It's just a convention in the end, many APIs do not even discriminate such details and simply return `HTTP 400 - BAD REQUEST` with a description of the error, even though it is semantically incorrect to use it (by convention) for requests issued with correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about database errors and how they fit with http status codes. My question was unclear about what I was trying to solve, I updated it to better reflect my purpose.